При попытке запуска проекта Eclipse выдает ошибку "Невозможно открыть файл"
Вчера всё работало нормально. Сегодня открываю Eclipse, запускаю Index.jsp и открывается Notepad++ (без ничего, просто запускается пустым), а над ним появляется сообщение об ошибке:

Невозможно открыть файл
"D:\Eclipse
(JavaEE)\eclipse\http:\localhost:8082\TastePalette\index.jsp" нельзя
открыть:
Папка "D:\Eclipse (JavaEE)\eclipse\http:\localhost:8082\TastePalette"
не существует

При этом в папке D:\Eclipse (JavaEE)\TastePalette всё есть и таких проблем раньше не возникало. Как сервер подключен Tomcat 9.0.
Решила проверить и создала новый динамический веб-проект. Его также нельзя запустить - также открывается Notepad++ и возникает такая же ошибка.
В чём может быть проблема?
